# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' in '/app/node_modules/react-native-aes-crypto'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, aescryptoserviceprovider

I want to use `react-native-aes-crypto` but it need `react-native`. I install it but it continue to say that it can't find it.

I have try to reinstall it, add his dependencies but nothing work.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "neko_web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.0.20",
    "@trendmicro/react-sidenav": "^0.4.5",
    "ajv": "^6.5.1",
    "create-react-app": "^1.5.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "react-icons-kit": "^1.1.5",
    "react-moment": "^0.7.7",
    "react-native": "^0.55.4",
    "react-native-aes-crypto": "^1.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "react-sidenav": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=3005 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

The error is getting when I do `import Aes from 'react-native-aes-crypto'`

UPDATE 1:

 I have tried to change version of react-native to 0.55.0, no more audit fix to do but it display the same error.

Comment: Did you installed react-native-cli?

Comment: No and I have take an another package for AES, but I think it's that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the package `react-native-cli` for fix that.

If you want an another package who doesn't require react-native, use `simple-encryptor`.