# react-native:Unable to import react-native after installing through npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I am in my initial stages of learning react and have a limited understanding of npm manager and importing libraries into project.
For my current project, I had installed react-native using

`npm install react-native`

This also reflects in my package.json and node_modules folder

`"react-native": "^0.61.5"`

Now, when I try to import react-native as follows into AppCarousel.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';
```

and then build the application , i get the following error message

```
.\src\Components\AppCarousel.js
Cannot find module: 'react-native'. Make sure this package is installed.

You can install this package by running: npm install react-native.


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react@1.0.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-09T13_08_54_364Z-debug.log
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

I tried referring to the the following questions i) [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041177/module-not-found-cant-resolve-react-native-in-app-node-modules-react-nativ) ii)[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54268511/why-is-importing-not-working-in-react-native)

I cannot make out if this is a bug in npm or if there is a lack of understanding for installing packages on my side. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Which else commands have ran at the time of installation?

Comment: @KaranMehta i did install other libraries using npm . For react-native, i only ran npm install react-native and also as the other answers suggested in the link, i tried installing react-native-cli as well using npm again, but that didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Terminal to kill the process:

```
ps -ax | grep npm
```

Then try to navigate to your directory in your terminal and try to do write this:

```
npm I react
```

or again:

```
npm i react-native
```

Simple explanation to get in use with TypeScript and React:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/typescript